# How to query the Media Remaining property on a printer via CUPS?

Tags: unix, printing, cups

I'm successfully using a DNP DS-620 printer via CUPS (`lp`/`loptions`) to set print options and print.

There is one thing I'm having issues with: retrieving the value of `Media Remaining` (how many more prints can be done with the currently loaded media).

I had a look at the [CUPS Programming Manual](https://www.cups.org/doc/cupspm.html) but I couldn't find anything pointing to retrieving the number of prints left with the current media.
Am I looking in the wrong place ? How can I programmatically "ask" the printer how many more prints it can do before changing media ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a thing about this printer model (never even had heard about DNP before). However, you can only get that info from CUPS (or from the printer directly), if that printer is designed to keep track of the amount of loaded media. Some printers can only distinguish between '0' sheets in the input tray and '1 or more' in the input tray.

If your printer does talk IPP (Internet Printing Protocol), you could run a CLI command, `ipptool` (which is bundled with CUPS) directly against the printer to query all its attributes, which would include an info (or not) about the loaded paper:

```
 ipptool -tv ipp://ip-address-of-printer:631/ipp/print get-printer-attributes.test
```

This may or may not help you get access to the info you want.